# Position of jquery ui Selectmenu

Tags: jquery-ui, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I have used below selectmenu script to initialize the selectmenu.

```
$("#year").selectmenu({style:'dropdown',maxHeight:400});
```

HTML code:

```
<select name="year" class="bubble year" id="year">
        <option value="">Year</option>
                <option value="">2000</option>
                <option value="">2001</option>
</select>
```

UI Selectmenu is generated is placed at the bottom of html. It is fine as per the requirement, but this generated selectmenu is not visible on the page due to below style applied to auto generated Div.

```
element.style {
        left: -1052.5px;
        position: relative;
        top: -2206.05px;
        z-index: 1;
}
```

Above style has been applied to class `.ui-selectmenu-menu`. So, due to `left` & `top` positioning, ui dropdown is not visible on the page.

My question is about positioning. How the above style is generated ?

Answer (score 2):

Which version of Selectmenu you are using? Working example or jsFiddle?

In latest versions, positioniong is done by jQuery UI Position Plugin. Earlier (deprecated) versions use built-in functionality.

Are you including all needed files and CSS?